# Selector field displaying as free text acumatica mobile

Tags: acumatica

I am trying to display WorkflowStage property as selector field just like in web application as screenshot below.

[image]

And this is the code that I have added in the xml file.

[image]

But still it gets rendered as a textbox field in mobile (free text) like this.
[image]

What is missing here?

Comment: Found one mistake. Changed to this in xml file.

`<sm:Field Name="WorkflowStage" SelectorDisplayFormat="KeyDescription">
      <sm:SelectorContainer FieldsToShow="2">
            <sm:Field Name="WorkflowStageID"   ListDisplayFormat="CaptionValue"/>
            <sm:Field Name="Description"   ListDisplayFormat="CaptionValue"/>
      </sm:SelectorContainer>
</sm:Field>`


But the issue still persists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of right now, Acumatica mobile apps do not support Tree Selectors used in various screens inside Acumatica. Adding Workflow Stage as a text box field is the only possible way to add such fields on a mobile device.

Comment: Ok. Thank you for your answer.